# Search a table based on multiple rows in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, entity-attribute-value, relational-division

Basically I have three MySQL tables:

**Users** - contains base information on users
**Fields** - describes additional fields for said users (e.g. location, dob etc.)
**Data** - Contains user data described via links to the fields table

With the basic design as follows (the below is a stripped down version)

**Users:**

```
 ID | username | password | email | registered_date
```

**Fields**

```
 ID | name | type
```

**Data:**

```
 ID | User_ID | Field_ID | value
```

what I want to do is search Users by the values for the fields they have, e.g. example fields might be:

Full Name
Town/City
Postcode
etc.

I've got the following, which works when you're only wanting to search by one field:

```
SELECT `users`.`ID`,
       `users`.`username`,
       `users`.`email`,
       `data`.`value`,
       `fields`.`name`

FROM `users`,
     `fields`,
     `data`

WHERE `data`.`Field_ID` = '2'
AND `data`.`value` LIKE 'london'
AND `users`.`ID` = `data`.`User_ID`
AND `data`.`Field_ID` = `fields`.`ID`

GROUP BY `users`.`ID`
```

But what about if you want to search for Multiple fields? e.g. say I want to search for Full Name "Joe Bloggs" With Town/City set to "London"? This is the real sticking point for me.

Is something like this possible with MySQL?

Comment: Why can you not just simply write `AND users.name ='Joe'` ?

Comment: Because the database is not structured in such a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going with the assumption that "searching multiple fields" is talking about the [Entity-Attribute-Value structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%2Dattribute%2Dvalue_model).

In that case, I propose that the first step is to create a derived query - basically, we want to limit the "EAV data joined" to *only* include the records that have the values we are interested in finding. (I've altered some column names, but the same premise holds.)

```
SELECT d.userId
FROM data d
JOIN fields f
  ON f.fieldId = d.fieldId
-- now that we establish data/field relation, filter rows
WHERE f.type = "location" AND d.value = "london"
   OR f.type = "job" AND d.value = "programmer"
```

This resulting rows are derived from the *filtered* EAV triplets that match our conditions. Only the userId is selected in this case (as it will be used to join against the user relation), but it is also possible to push fieldId/value/etc through.

Then we can use *all of this* as a derived query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users u
JOIN (
  -- look, just goes in here :)
  SELECT DISTINCT d.userId
  FROM data d
  JOIN fields f
    ON f.fieldId = d.fieldId
  WHERE f.type = "location" AND d.value = "london"
     OR f.type = "job" AND d.value = "programmer"
) AS e
ON e.userId = u.userId
```

Notes:

1. The query planner will figure all the RA stuff out peachy keen; don't worry about this "nesting" as there is no dependent subquery.
2. I avoid the use of implicit cross-joins as I feel they muddle most queries, this case being a particularly good example.
3. I've "cheated" and added a DISTINCT to the derived query. This will ensure that at most one record will be joined/returned per user and avoids the use of GROUP BY.

---

While the above gets "OR" semantics well (it's both easier and I may have misread the question), modifications are required to get "AND" semantics. Here are some ways that the derived query can be written to get such. (And at this point I must apologize to Tony - I forget that I've already done all the plumbing to generate such queries trivially in my environment.)

Count the number of matches to ensure that all rows match. This will only work if each entity is unique per user. It also eliminates the need for DISTINCT to maintain correct multiplicity.

```
SELECT d.userId
FROM data d
JOIN fields f
  ON f.fieldId = d.fieldId
-- now that we establish data/field relation, filter rows
WHERE f.type = "location" AND d.value = "london"
   OR f.type = "job" AND d.value = "programmer"
GROUP BY d.userId
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Find the intersecting matches:

```
SELECT d.userId
FROM data d
JOIN fields f ON f.fieldId = d.fieldId  
WHERE f.type = "location" AND d.value = "london"
INTERSECT
SELECT d.userId
FROM data d
JOIN fields f ON f.fieldId = d.fieldId  
WHERE f.type = "job" AND d.value = "programmer"
```

Using JOINS (see Tony's answer).

```
SELECT d1.userId
FROM data d1
JOIN data d2   ON d2.userId = d1.userId
JOIN fields f1 ON f1.fieldId = d1.fieldId
JOIN fields f2 ON f2.fieldId = d2.fieldId
-- requires AND here across row
WHERE f1.type = "location" AND d1.value = "london"
  AND f2.type = "job"      AND d2.value = "programmer"
```

An inner JOIN itself provides conjunction semantics when applied outside of the condition. In this case I show "re-normalize" the data. This can also be written such that [sub-]selects appear in the select clause.

```
SELECT userId
FROM (
  -- renormalize, many SO questions on this
  SELECT q1.userId, q1.value as location, q2.value as job
  FROM (SELECT d.userId, d.value
     FROM data d
     JOIN fields f ON f.fieldId = d.fieldId
     WHERE f.type = "location") AS q1
  JOIN (SELECT d.userId, d.value
     FROM data d
     JOIN fields f ON f.fieldId = d.fieldId
     WHERE f.type = "job") AS q2
  ON q1.userId = q2.userId
) AS q
WHERE location = "london"
  AND job = "programmer"
```

The above duplicity is relatively easy to generate via code and some databases (such as SQL Server) support CTEs which make writing such much simpler. YMMV.

Comment: Thanks :) does almost exactly what I want, the only extra thing being that it would be good if it could also display the field types and values along with the output (but I think I can figure this out on my own!).

Comment: In fact, the above mostly works, but say I want to search for "Programmers" who only live in "London" the above example doesn't work, as it will return any programmer (regardless of where they live) and anyone living in London (regardless of their profession)?

Comment: @SeanDunwoody Added a bit for that.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, this is what you want:

```
FROM `users`,
     `fields`,
     `data` `location`
     `data` `name`

WHERE `location`.`Field_ID` = '2'
AND `location`.`value` LIKE 'london'
AND `location`.`Field_ID` = `fields`.`ID`
AND `name`.`Field_ID` = 'whathere? something for its name'
AND `name`.`value` LIKE 'london'
AND `name`.`Field_ID` = `fields`.`ID`
AND `users`.`ID` = `data`.`User_ID`
```

I'd prefer joins though

Answer (score 0):

Well here you hit one of the downsides of the EAV you are using

```
SELECT u.ID, u.username,u.email, d1.value, f1.Name, d2.Value, f2.name
FROM `users` u,
inner join data d1 On d1.User_id = u.id
inner join data d2 On d2.User_id = u.id
inner join fields f1 on f1.id = d1.field_id
inner join fields f2 on f2.id = d2.field_id
WHERE d1.Field_id = '2' and d1.Value = 'london'
and d2.field_id = '??' and d2.value = 'Joe Bloggs' 
GROUP BY `users`.`ID`
```

Messy isn't it? Bet you can't wait to go for, four or five values. Or think about (Forename = Joe  Or surname = Bloggs) and City = London...

Comment: Er, come again. Select u.id, n.FullName,a.City From Users u inner join Names n On n.id = u.id inner join addresses a on a.name_id = u.id

Comment: Needing to join the same relation (or set of relations) multiple times is not an inherent problem with EAV.

Comment: The joins being unintelligible and seriously verbose is though, which is what I was referring to.

Comment: Or Nosql, or for the hard of thinking ObjectStore. :(

Comment: I've redacted my previous comments. I forgot how annoying it was to write conjunction queries without the use of CTEs or generators - I guess I've been spoiling myself :(